# Which softwares (in terms of software function, rather than name) are necessary to program an indie game in c++ on mac?

Tags: c++, macos

I am interested in programming an indie game on my mac. I understand there is software such as DirectX, DirectX SDK, Visual C++ which is available only for Microsoft OS. Firstly, what functions do these softwares have and why are they required? Why could a simple editor, like vim, not perform the same task?

I understand the overarching question seems rather broad as there may be equivalent softwares available for mac for which people have their particular preferences. Therefore, I am not asking for this directly (although a few examples of preferred softwares for mac would be useful). Instead, I am asking which softwares are necessary and sufficient in terms of the function they perform in order to develop an indie game on a mac.

*As an example of an answer:* 'a compiler is a necessity, as it is required to compile source code and run c++ programs'
*Optionaly*: For example g++

Many thanks!

Comment: "necessary and sufficient" are very opinion-based terms.  You could, with great difficulty, create a game without any of the mentioned software.  And, based on your needs, you may find that some subset of these prove very valuable for your particular game.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler and a text editor.  Using the standard library, you can write a basic text adventure.

A debugger is relatively key, so you can see the state of your program in the middle of execution.  Some people program without using one much.

Having a solution system (be it make and makefiles or whatever) makes building less of a pain.  Having a source control repository and utilities will allow you to reverse changes when you make serious screwups, provide a backup for your local source when your system dies half way through the project.  Diff tools to see what you did in a particular changeset can be useful to track down bugs.

If you want a graphical game, you'll need a graphics library, or a library that includes a graphics library, for your platform of choice.  This may or may not imply an application architecture (like a message pump).  Different styles of graphics (hypercard-esque, 2d sidescroller, isometric, 3d free-move, etc) can find different graphical libraries useful.

If you want a traditional GUI with buttons, text rendered from fonts, and scroll bars and the like, reinventing the wheel will take a bunch of time, and early prototypes (where you care less about look&feel than you do about other problems) will take longer.  So a framework that provides for that can be useful.

An IDE (integrated development environment) like MSVC or Eclipse usually hooks together a solution building system (including compiler) with a text editor and a debugger, and can have hooks to attach to a source control system and changeset difference viewer.  The functions an IDE provide are available piecemeal: IDEs just integrate them all into one package.